# Do i have to integrate my SSL certificate into my PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, security, ssl, https

I have a SSL certificate installed (on DirectAdmin) succesfully, and i have a secure connection (the green lock button appears).

Do i have to integrate the certificate into my PHP code?
(My provider does'nt give support for ".pem" files)

For example, do i need to secure the sample code below with SSL (excluding validating the user input, hashing the password, etc.) and could you give an example or resource where i can find howto?

```
<?php
$srvr = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pswd = "password";
$dtbs = "users";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($srvr, $user, $pswd, $dtbs);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New user created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

PS. The final system will have confidential data of clients and i know how to secure the script, only i'm not familiar with SSL yet and i'm learning that part.

Comment: No, SSL usually has nothing to do with the application. You just give the certificate to the host (in a secure fashion - don't email it!) and they will install it. Or, they will give you facilities to do it yourself. If they don't know how to do this, maybe you need a host who does?

Comment: The webserver SSL certificate has nothing to do with the MySQL connection (albeit that could be encrypted too; different key, hardly anyone does).

Comment: SSL won't much help though, as you have two whacking great security vulnerabilities here: SQL injection and unhashed passwords.

Comment: No you dont have to do anything with your PHP scripts for SSL, however you should really look up SQL injection as your code is vulnerable

Comment: "The final system will ... have confidential data of clients" ... uh oh `:-)`.

Comment: I know the code is vulnerable, it was just an quick example for the idea, it's not the real code im using :) Offcourse i will secure it with a strong hashing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked whether your PHP code needs to know about the SSL certificate you use to secure your web users' connections to your web server.

The answer is **no**. If you've installed it in the appropriate place for your web server, that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The ssl cert in itself it on the frontline of your app. All https requests to and from server are encrypted. That is what you paid for. The php code is seperate in my opinion. I normally have connection files hidden away in my projects include folder outside the application root and call them when needed. However your code is vulnerable for sql injection at present so you will want to fix that before you move forward.

You can also go one step further to manually encrypt the connection file.

Comment: Encrypt the connection file (or any file containing confidential information) is a good idea. But can you give an example or resource of how this can be done and that is still readable for php?

Comment: If you encrypt the connection details, then you'll need a decryption password available somewhere so they can be decrypted whenever the app needs to make a connection. It doesn't really matter where you store that, since the app will need to obtain it, and if the app can do that, a hacker who has got into the server can probably do so too. This is generally why most connection passwords (as distinct from user passwords) are left unencrypted/unhashed.

Comment: What about encrypting the whole website with HTML Guard or something simular? Is this really adding much more safety or is it easy to decrypt?

Comment: This will not add more safety and as halfer said the decrytion password has to be stored somewhere so if the app can reach it so can the hacker. your highest priority is to make your script sql-injection proof. As this is a common way hackers use to gain access to your info

Comment: Okay thanks all of you. I cannot give vote's yet, but i will if i can ;). A better answer/help in this question i could'nt get!